# How to cancel the creation of a view in Eclipse RCP e4?

Tags: eclipse, exception, rcp, e4, postconstruct

Is it possible to cancel the creation of a view in the `@PostConstruct` phase? I have:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    try {
        // do something where an exception is thrown
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // I want to cancel construction, close the view and show an error dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to cancel a lot of views just put the error message in the view instead of the normal contents.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the part service hide part immediately after the part creation has finished using something like:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent, UISynchronize uiSync,
                          EPartService partService, MPart part)
{
  // Other code

  // Run hidePart as soon as possible after part creation has finished

  uiSync.asyncExec(() -> partService.hidePart(part));
}
```

(Above is using Java 8 lambda).

Answer (score 0):

Just close the view, e4 style

```
MPart part = partService.findPart(viewId);
part.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: `setVisible(false)` doesn't close the view. `setToBeRendered(false)` destroys the view object, but I'm not sure that will run correctly during the part construction.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But @greg-449 point is what I was also wondering about. Does setVisibile() really destroy the whole part? setToBeRendered() unfortunately does not work, as it leaves the view open.